# How to ask Siri to tell me the news

Tags: siri

Siri seems to be smart enough to fetch some news for me, but let's say I just want to find out the news in my country.

I asked `Tell me the news` and the answer was: *Here's some news for 'tell me the news'*.

I tried `Tell me the breaking news` and the answer was: *Here's some news for 'Breaking'*.

So, how to ask Siri about the Breaking news and news in general?

Comment: You could try something like “What’s the latest in San Francisco?” replacing San Francisco with your city

Comment: @LukaKerrΔ Thanks! That fetches it from Twitter, which is not bad, but I think there should be another way to ask for *news*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The News app and features for iOS 10 are only limited to the USA, UK and Austraila at the moment. http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#news

In these countries, if you were to ask Siri for example:

> What's the latest in New York City

Sir would respond with a list of articles from the News app.

However, if you are outside these countries. For example, I am in Toronto, Canada and if I ask Siri a similar question:

> What's the latest in Toronto

Siri first asks for confirmation to use a Twitter account to recommend more personalised results if you don't have one signed in or don't allow Siri access to Twitter. Siri will display a list of Tweets related to the location of Toronto.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but then, is there a solution to get the news, but not from Twitter?

Comment: Currently not natively in iOS 10, if you do not live in those currencies that have the News app. There maybe an app on the store that supports Siri's new API that is a news related.